# Swallowing an error in my observable and returning a cached value - all keep the subscription alive

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Please save my sanity.  I'm trying to do some error handling inside my observable.  I've followed heaps of articles but it hasn't clicked.  I'd rather handle errors inside the service and push out the cached data if an error occurs.

I do this inside my angular2 component...

```
private initializeJobPolling() {
    this.subscription = Observable
        .interval(5000)
        .startWith(0)
        .flatMap(() => {
            return this.jobService.getJobs();
        })
        .subscribe(
            (jobsContainer: any) => {
                let allJobs: IJob[] = jobsContainer.jobs.map(j => new Job(j));
                this.allJobs = allJobs;
            }            );
}
```

and inside jobService...

```
getJobs() {
    let thisService = this;
    return thisService.http.get('app/services/jobs.json')
        .map((responseData) => {
            console.log('getting Jobs from API');
            thisService.allJobs = responseData.json();
            return thisService.allJobs;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [catch](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/catchproto.md):

```
getJobs() {
  return this.http.get('app/services/jobs.json')
    .map((responseData) => {
      console.log('getting Jobs from API');
      this.allJobs = responseData.json();
      return this.allJobs;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      return Observable.just(this.allJobs);
    });
}
```

**Update**:

As pointed out in the comments, RxJS 5 doesn't have `.just`, so use `.of` instead:

```
getJobs() {
  return this.http.get('app/services/jobs.json')
    .map((responseData) => {
      console.log('getting Jobs from API');
      this.allJobs = responseData.json();
      return this.allJobs;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      return Observable.of(this.allJobs);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've just tried that but it won't transpile...   Property 'just' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.   I do have 
import 'rxjs/Rx';

Comment: That is odd. Are you importing such where you need to do `Rx.Observable.just`? [Documentation is here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/return.md).

Comment: Very odd.  If I look at the file that  import 'rxjs/Rx' calls, it has a list of heaps of operators (map etc), but no mention of 'just'.

Comment: There are so many various builds of Observable, but I'm surprised `just` is omitted. There's also an `Observable.return` and `Observable.returnValue` that mean the same thing; maybe your build has _those_ instead?

Comment: They just don't seem to exist anywhere in my rxjs nodemodules folder...

Comment: Use Observable.of instead

Comment: The documentation links you provided are for RxJS 4. RxJS 5 is what is used with ng2. `just` -> `of`